# What's the difference between post attributive and complement？

Tags: complements, attributives

> After six months of arguing and final 16 hours of hot parliamentary debates, Australia's Northern Territory became the first legal authority in the world to allow doctors to take the lives of incurably ill patients who wish to die.

In the above sentence, the **to allow doctors to take the lives of incurably ill patients who wish to die** is a complement? or post attributive? What's the difference between post attributive and complement？and **to allow** is a infinitive？

Comment: Yes, "allow" is an infinitive. The infinitival clause in bold is a relative clause functioning as a modifier in the noun phrase _the first legal authority in the world to allow doctors to take the lives of incurably ill patients who wish to die_.

Comment: Incidentally, "attributive" means **before** the noun, whereas "post" means **after** the noun.  So there's no such thing as 'post attributive'.

Answer (score 1):

> ... *Australia's Northern Territory became* [*the first legal*
> *authority in the world to allow doctors to take the lives of incurably*
> *ill patients who wish to die*].

It's an infinitival relative clause functioning as a modifier in the bracketed noun phrase.

Infinitival relative clauses typically have a modal meaning comparable to that expressed in finites by "can" or "should".

In your example, the meaning is

*the first legal authority in the world that can allow* *doctors to take the lives of incurably ill patients who wish to die*.